# PostgreSQL efficient database structure

Tags: postgresql, database-design

I am scraping products from a website. Each product has a price history table that contains a historical price with the associated date and store name. I would like to store this information in a database (it will be used to create graphs for each product). I was thinking of creating two tables. One would be a *Product* table with a *product_id* column [PK] and *name* column. The other would be a *Price History* table with a *product_id* column [FK], *price* column, *date* column, and *store* column. Is there a more efficient structure I could adopt?

Comment: No, that is the correct set of tables to use given the use case you've described.

Comment: More efficient from what perspective?

Answer (score 1):

If you need a relational structure (you intend to query `PRODUCT_HISTORY`), then what you described is the way to go.

If you want a more document-oriented structure (you never query `PRODUCT_HISTORY` and only work with it as part of Product), then you can turn it into a structure like JSON and store it directly in `PRODUCTS` table.

Answer (score 1):

Your setup is a good option to do it. If you need more information about the stores (store name, street address, city etc), you could add table `store` with needed fields and have `store_id` in history table a FK to it.

Don't use spaces and capital letters in table names, your main table name could be for example `price_history`